# Entity Framework renaming mistake

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework Code First in my project, and I did something quite silly I can't fix. I have renamed a table in SQL Server Management Studio, and then deleted it there. I then recreated the correct table (just an 's' that wasn't supposed to be here). Now it's not here anymore and I keep getting exceptions in my queries since EF looks for a table that does not exist anymore (even though I renamed it everywhere!). Now my table is called `RelImpUser` and it used to be `RelImpUsers`.

So I have tried recreating the table in SQL Server, then making a migration with :

```
    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.RelImpUsers");
    }
```

But this does not delete my table. And everytime I execute a query, it looks in `RelImpUsers`, it does not go for `RelImpUser` which is the only name I put in my code. Any ideas how to fix this? I can add some code if you want, I just felt it doesn't help much here.

**Edit 1:** It might have to do with the pluralization of my tables. So all my tables all had plural names, but the new one doesn't, BUT EF still pluralizes because I checked the option when creating DB Code First.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend going scorched earth on this one. Delete the database from SQL, delete your migrations from your project and reinitialize from your data model (after you've corrected the table name that is)

Comment: Which version of EF please ?

Comment: Version 6.0.0.0 and I'm goin for @Ortund 's suggestion, since I need to move my project to a VM, it's not really a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code First uses its models to build the queries. You will need to annotate your RelImpUser class (or add comparable fluent code):

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("RelImpUser")]
public class RelImpUser
{
    public int RelImpID { get; set; }
    public string Field1{ get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Fluent equivalent:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RelImpUser>().ToTable("RelImpUser");
```

If you don't want pluralized names, you can turn that convention off:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't like working with the Fluent API? Honestly, given these options, I'd absolutely opt for the DataAnnotation before I add in fluent code

Comment: I much prefer fluent code. Separation of concerns. Like to keep my POCOs P :)

Comment: But then, the annotation has to point towards the pluralized table? Meaning `[Table("RelImpUsers")]`, or keep it singular?

Comment: @LéonardLaiter the data annotation will tell Entity Framework "this class is that table".

Comment: You said all your tables except this one are plural, so you probably want to keep the convention. Use the annotation (or fluent equivalent) to override it.

Comment: Ah ok I understand. Thanks!